# How can I improve the architecture of my React application

Tags: reactjs, architecture, redux

I have a navbar which has a child sub-navbar component that opens below it when a toggle button on navbar is clicked. On the sub-navbar is a child dropdown menu that contains a number of options with onClick props that need to do two things in sequence:

1. the intended action (e.g. go to the "/login" route, trigger logout
   action, etc)
2. hide the sub-navbar

FWIW I have a redux action to hide the sub-navbar, and routing is done via react-router v4. This all works fine currently, and I've attempted to force myself to keep to the [presentational (dumb) components vs containers pattern](https://medium.com/@dan_abramov/smart-and-dumb-components-7ca2f9a7c7d0) but in doing so feel I have a mess.

For example to keep the dropdown options component dumb I have the navbar container with two functions:

```
handleSubheaderItemClicked = (funcToExec, data) => {  
  funcToExec(data)
  this.props.dispatch(hideSubheader)
};

handleLoginClicked = () => {
  this.props.history.push("/login")
};
```

These functions get passed to the (dumb) subheader child component as props, and passed again through to the child dropdown component which has property

```
onClick={() => { this.props.handleItemClicked(this.props.handleLoginClicked)}}
```

Am I abusing this pattern? It seems convoluted but it would also seem dirty to give some low level component access to hideSubheader() action and router history.

Is there another approach I'm missing?

---

*P.S I know using an anonymous function in render() is bad, I just wrote it like this for compactness*

Comment: Use Redux and Saga accordingly as the app becomes more complex

Answer (score 1):

You're 90% of the way there, but you overlooked one important aspect of "presentational components".  From the link you provided about presentational (dumb) components;

> Rarely have their own state (when they do, it’s UI state rather than data).

That parentheses portion is important.

Your example is a perfect showcase of "UI state".  Opening and closing a menu is 100% UI.  And as such, it makes sense to hold that logic within the menu component, not within redux.

What you want is something that looks a bit like this in your subheader child component;

```
handleOnClick() {
    this.setState({menuOpen: false});
    this.props.onClick();
}
```

Exact structure will details that are hard to glean from your description, but hopefully this puts you in the right direction.

Comment: I aggre with thiw answer, Is not incorrect to use the react state when you need to work with the UI state.